# How can I reduce the delay in my output box in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, performance, textbox, delay

The idea is that a new window pops-up where you can see what is happening. The problem is: there is a 20 second delay before anything shows up in the pop-up window. I can verify that because in the console output I can see directly what's happening. It starts at the beginning in the pop-up window and the pop-up disappears before all records are shown because the program is already 20 seconds ahead.
Anyone knows how to show a pop-up window and directly show output?

```
If DgvObj.CheckRecords(100, 1) = 1 Then
    Dim dialog As New OutputBox("archive") With {
        .Width = 400,
        .Height = 200
        }
    dialog.Show()
    dialog.textBox.Text = "Waiting..." & Environment.NewLine
        
    Dim order_num As String
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DgvObj.DataGridName(1).Rows
        order_num = row.Cells("Order").Value
        dialog.textBox.AppendText("Archive record " & row.Index + 1 & " Order: " & order_num & Date.Now & Environment.NewLine)
        Console.WriteLine("Archive record " & row.Index + 1 & " Order: " & order_num & Date.Now)
        FormArchiveren(order_num, True)
    Next
    dialog.Close()
End If
```

Comment: If the DataGridView has a DataSource, you can process the DataSource in a Task and use `Progress<T>` to update your TextBox. If you want to use a single thread, you have to refresh your TextBox, which adds some more `ms` to your procedure each iteration. Is this dialog worth it? Maybe a simple ProgressBar can be enough.

Comment: add the one line Applicaiton.DoEvents() right after you msg box display. (well, ok, right after the line that sets waiting....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do something in a windows app, like you click a button and the code inside the buttonclick handler starts calculating Pi to a trillion decimals places etc, you prevent the thread that handles all the UI updates from going back to its work of keeping the UI alive and responsive. This means the display in the app appears to hang while the work is carried out - it's a common problem and there are probably tens of thousands of questions on SO asking about it

The answer is always the same, and very simple; don't make the thread that processes your button click event take a long time to do anything. Less than 50 milliseconds is generally OK. Any operation that takes longer than 50ms, don't do it on the same thread the processes the event handler

There are many ways to solve this, and the simplest and nastiest is simply to regularly tell the UI thread, whose attention you've captured, to go and process all the UI updates that are pending; insert `Application.DoEvents()` after you set the textbox AppendText

Preferably, a nearly equally simple way is to use Task-based Async Pattern; make the work you do in FormArchiveren asyncronous*, make the method return a Task, make your click handler (or whatever event starts this process) async, and Await FormArchiveren(order_num, True)

Alternative ways that involve a bit more coding, and are falling out of favour these days, are things like using a BackgroundWorker or true multithreaded solution. They're less used because they're complex to get right (though backgroundworker is easier)

Be aware that if you do this (TAP, BackgroundWorker or separate thread executing FormArchiveren), you should not access UI controls from within FormArchiveren because the thread doing the work is not the thread that created the UI control, and that's a basic tenet of windows forms coding; thou shalt not use any thread other than the thread that created a control, to update anything about the control

*<sub>Making FormArchiveren async might be trivial, or could be more involved, but to offer any kind of sensible advice on it we'd need to see the definition of it (and anything else it calls on that is also part of your program. At its most trivial it would be switching to using existing Async versions of sync methods it already calls. If it does a lot of sync work itself forwhich there isn't an existing async version, then setting up tasks and running them yourself would be the "a bit more involved" bit</sub>

Comment: While the above is great advice? The message box is in fact a waiting - I am doing something. Even if you thread this work, the user still needs to display that waiting until done message. And even if you split out to another thread - the user still wants that waiting message. If there was no waiting message required, then sure, a separate thread makes sense. But the requirement here is that wafting message - threaded or not, it really don't change the basic requirement here.

Comment: Note with `Async` and `Await`, if you're doing something CPU-bound, it won't magically help out with keeping the UI responsive.  In that case, you will need to do something (like `Task.Run`) to ensure that the CPU-bound work is happening off the UI thread.

Comment: @Craig errr... yes. How were you thinking it would work otherwise?

Comment: I'm sure you know that, I'm much less sure that the questioner knows that.  It's the sort of thing I didn't at all have a handle on when I was first learning how to use the async features.  This might also be a good place to mention Stephen Cleary's extensive blog postings on async, which were a huge help to me in grokking it.

Comment: I'm not sure if my notes actually merit any changes to the (otherwise excellent) answer, though.

Comment: If you all don't mind I used the line Application.DoEvents() and it worked almost like I wanted to. It didn't want to scroll but I fixed that in my way. The whole async stuff I keep for later reading. I'll keep it in mind. Thanks for the quick answer even when I could have found it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the stats display update by using application.DoEvents

eg this:

```
If DgvObj.CheckRecords(100, 1) = 1 Then
Dim dialog As New OutputBox("archive") With {
    .Width = 400,
    .Height = 200
    }
dialog.Show()
dialog.textBox.Text = "Waiting..." & Environment.NewLine
Application.DoEvents()
 
Dim order_num As String
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DgvObj.DataGridName(1).Rows
    order_num = row.Cells("Order").Value
    dialog.textBox.AppendText("Archive record " & row.Index + 1 & " Order: " & order_num & Date.Now & Environment.NewLine)
    
    Console.WriteLine("Archive record " & row.Index + 1 & " Order: " & order_num & Date.Now)
    Applicaton.DoEvents()
    FormArchiveren(order_num, True)
Next
dialog.Close()
End If
```

Note that EVEN if you accept the other recommended advice to move this out to another thread? You will need to use doevents or some form of refresh for that display to update while the loop and code runs. So, while a separate thread is a good idea, it will not solve nor fix the basic issue you have that during a code loop, you have to give a command for the display to update during that process.

I should also point out that doevents is HEAVY, and for a loop of more then say 100 rows? You want to put some code in to only fire that doevents every 100 rows, or every half second. So, for large processing, I suggest much caution with this approach.

Comment: Sooo.. what are the two words highlighted in the middle of my answer, by use of an inline code block? It says *insert `Application.DoEvents()` after ... textbox AppendText*. From the posting times of my answer and your answer it seems like, 2 hours after I posted advice saying *"you can use DoEvents"*, you come along and berate me for suggesting threading (actually my strongest recommendation was for TAP) and then post an answer that parrots "you can use DoEvents", and take the oppo to have another pop with advice that isn't true; a threaded route would InvokeRequired/Invoke not DoEvents

Comment: Did not berate anyone. The jest of your post and narrative was to move the code out to a separate thread. And to USE threads. You spend SIGNFICANT time in your thread making that point. So when I referenced your advice, the context, the time, and what was stated was RATHER clear. Even if you come in and note doevents, the bulk of your post, and the point and the suggestion you were and DID make was ALL ABOUT how people should move this out to the separate thread. So own what you stated and claimed. Adding in this doevents can be used changes zero about the BULK of your point and narrative.

Comment: No, it really wasn't. The only time I mentioned moving this code to a separate thread was in the 3 words *" or true multithreaded solution"*. I mention the word *thread* throughout the answer because I'm talking about the UI thread while educating the OP as to how windows forms program work and why they appear to hang when the thread executing button click handler code is made busy for a long time.. DoEvents is about the worst and nastiest way to resolve the "my app is hanging" problem, and you don't even point this out, you falsely state it's the only way to solve the problem!

Comment: Context dude! You spent significant text promoting use of async task approaches - which by the way is a threated approach! (did you forget this???). You can't stand here and narrate about task based async WITHOUT a context of meaning a threaded approach. So yes, you talked about threading, and THEN WENT ON at length about suggesting and using task async - which ALSO happens to be a topic and context about threading.  (unless you going to claim that it is not?).So context of threading and that of task based async approaches are one and the same in this context.  Quite much your whole post.

Comment: Sure, still need doevents is not the best context - I have corrected that.